# align properties by column with webstorm

Tags: webstorm

How can I cofigure WebStorm aligning for less that will make it possible to align properties just like `bootstrap` less files have:

```
@navbar-default-color:             #777;
@navbar-default-bg:                #fff;
@navbar-default-border:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);
@navbar-default-box-shadow:        0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 14, 0.1);
```

Currenly when I apply formatting I get the following:

```
@navbar-default-color: #777;
@navbar-default-bg: #fff;
@navbar-default-border: darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);
@navbar-default-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(17, 16, 14, 0.1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can align CSS properties by setting `Settings | Code Style | CSS, Other, Align values: on colon`

Comment: Would be nice if your answer contained some explanation

Comment: Thanks, it does work except for the file where all `less` variables are contained. I'm wondering. Any thoughts?

Comment: not sure I follow you. Do you mean that this option doesn't affect .less files? Works for me... Code snippet might be helpful

Comment: No, it works OK with .less files. But it doesn't work for the less file which contains less variables like these `@screen-sm: 768px;@screen-lg: 930px;` etc.

Comment: ah, I see. 'Align values' option doesn't affect variables. Please vote for [WEB-12539](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12539)